# Show sent POST Values with Fiddler..How do i do that?

Tags: fiddler

I make some requests to a site and i want to see, what kind of variables has been sent to the server..

May be its possible with `fiddler` but i can't figure it out, how to do it..

Comment: How do you make the requests to a site? Ajax?

Answer (score 48):

You can do this in Fiddler using the following steps.

- Locate the request in fiddler that relates to the post - you should be able to see the URL you expect in the URL column.
- Select that line and the detailed view will open. There is a WebForms tab (inside "Inspectors") that displays the POST data in a neat table. You can also see it in the Raw tab, but it isn't nicely formatted like the WebForms tab.

I have made a screenshot to help you:

[image: Fiddler POST values]

Answer (score 6):

POST data can be seen in the `Inspectors -> Raw` window which will display the whole request along with POST data and headers.

**EDIT:** Yep... The `Inspectors -> WebForms` dialog would be another way however I usually don't make much use of it... Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Just click on the request in the `Web Sessions` pane, Then click `WebForms` tab within the `Inspectors` tab on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem but the answers here did not help me.
WebForms does not display json posted data. I figured out for posted json data, you need to check the Textview tab.

[image]

To summarise:

- Inspectors->WebForms: will show you classic html form posted values.
- Inspectors->Textview: will show you json and text posted values.