# Why does my request body have HTML in it?

Tags: html, json, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I have a Svelte application that is making an API POST request from a server-side form action named `savechanges`. The code is as follows:

```js
savechanges: async ({ params, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const body = { toggled: data.get("toggled"), channel: data.get("channel"), role: data.get("role") };

    const update_res = await fetch(`https://myapi.com`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { auth: API_KEY, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: body,
    });
    const update = await update_res.json();

    return update ? update : { success: false };
}
```

If I log the variable `body` I see this output

```
{
  toggled: 'false',
  channel: '793818346595418113',
  role: '780844467565494302'
}
```

which is exactly what it's meant to look like.

Despite this, whenever I attempt to send this request I get this error in my terminal:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<html>
<h"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (/path/to/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:580:15)
    at successSteps (/path/to/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:520:23)
    at /path/to/app/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/util.js:821:56
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have no idea why my request is trying to post HTML content or where its even coming from. If anyone can see something I have missed here that would be amazing!

Comment: Does Fiddler help with figuring out where the html is coming from? [Show sent POST Values with Fiddler..How do i do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6939681/1115360)

Comment: I've used another Node.js application (not Svelte) to send API requests to the same endpoint and it worked fine, so I think its something Svelte is doing maybe?

Comment: Could something be going awry by using an interpolated string literal for `https://myapi.com`?

Comment: That could be the case. I'm using that because the full URL (which I haven't posted here) includes a URI paramter that I am getting from the `params` object Svelte provides server functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting html because the response is an error page.

Convert your Javascript object to JSON.

```
const update_res = await fetch(`https://myapi.com`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { auth: API_KEY, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
});
```

Also, you can check the response in chrome devtools unter the netwrok tab.